# open source alternative to diffbot analyze API java

Tags: java

For an assignment I was given I need to write a web application in Java that, among other things, can differentiate webpages based on their content (whether it's an article, or a product or something else). I know the Diffbot Analyze API can do that, but I can only use Open Source or free APIs.
So, does any of you know of something that coulp help me?